# Importing Jtransforms library into android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to include the JTransforms-3.0-javadoc.jar file into my project in android studio and have looked at similar questions here but I do not seem to be having any luck. Does any one here know the steps required to get it to work?

Answer (score 9):

Put your jar inside `libs` directory and add this line to `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

Since JTransforms is on Maven, instead of jar you can also use:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.wendykierp:JTransforms:3.0'
    ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
Gradle has been updated and deprecated `compile` and now use `implementation` like this:

```
dependencies {
    ... 
    implementation 'com.github.wendykierp:JTransforms:3.1'
}
```

Comment: When I do that and run "Clean project" I get an error saying "Gradle DLS method not found: 'compile()' ". It says the possible causes are "The project 'project'  may be using a version  of Gradle that does not contain the method" or "The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin".

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I think I figured it out, I was putting it in the build.gradle file in the gradle folder but I should have put it in the build.gradle folder in the src folder in app, yes?

Comment: Exactly - `build.gradle` inside your app module. Path: your-project/app/build.gradle

Comment: Thank you so much for helping :) When I try import it in my code though, it gives me errors? If I, for example, try to `import org.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D;`, it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'DoubleFFT_1D'". Any thoughts?

Comment: I edited my answer. Or you can also replace old jar with this one: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/github/wendykierp/JTransforms/3.0/JTransforms-3.0.jar . Then sync gradle and build project.